# % operator on chars and event handling in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, operators, modulo

While reading  about event handling with Tkinter, I found out the piece of code below.

Can somebody explain to me what is the purpose of the *modulo operator* here and how it works, assuming the following declaration of `show_event_details` function:

```
def show_event_details(event):     
    event_name = {"2": "KeyPress", "4": "ButtonPress", "6": "Motion", "9":"FocusIn"}
    print ('='*50)
    print ("EventName=" + event_name[str(event.type)])
    print ("EventKeySymbol=" + str(event.keysym))
    print ("EventType=" + str(event.type))
    print ("EventWidgetId=" + str(event.widget))
    print ("EventCoordinate (x,y)=(" + str(event.x)+","+str(event.y)+")")
    print ("Time:", str(event.time))
```

The code:

```
alphanum = 'ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789'

for i in alphanum:
  mye.bind("<KeyPress-%s>"%i, show_event_details)

keysyms = ['Alt_L', 'Alt_R','BackSpace', 'Cancel', 'Caps_Lock','Control_L',
       'Control_R','Delete', 'Down', 'End', 'Escape', 'Execute','F1',
       'F2', 'Home', 'Insert', 'Left','Linefeed','KP_0','KP_1','KP_2',
       'KP_3','KP_4','KP_5','KP_6','KP_7','KP_8','KP_9','KP_Add',
       'KP_Decimal','KP_Divide']

for i in keysyms:
  mye.bind("<KeyPress-%s>"%i, show_event_details)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the code block you have, the % operator is being used to format the string. If you notice, the following line:

```
mye.bind("<KeyPress-%s>"%i, show_event_details)
```

Has "%s inside the string, and the % operator afterwards. This is essentially telling Python that it will be given an argument, which should be converted into a string and placed there.

It is a convenient way of representing variables in strings with different presentations. In this case, it is converting the variable "i" to a string.

Answer (score 2):

`%` doubles as a string-formatting operator. The expression

```
"<KeyPress-%s>" % i
```

evaluates to a string in which `%s` is replaced by the value of `i`. (This explanation glosses over a few details, such as why `%s` is used and how things change if the right-hand operand of `%` is a tuple instead of a single value. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) for more information.)